# Why I did not get effect the I want in storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard

I add the segmented Control to storyboard, but I did not get the result I want.

This is I add from the storyboard:

[image]

But you can see there is white corners here.

The effect I want is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Tint color of Your UISegmentedControl to white like in attached screenshots
[image]

By this UISegmentedControl will look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the tint color of the segmented control, by code like this

`[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:YOUR_COLOR];`

OR

if you have an outlet then like this 
`self.segmentedControl.tintColor = YOUR_COLOR;`

Comment: Can I set the tint color in storyboard?

Comment: If there should has the border color?